# How do you list items with and without labels from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, command-line, uti

Is there a command that can tell the label status (labels as applied in the info menu in the finder cmd+i) of an item from the command-line in OS X? Essentially, I just want to list all the items with or without labels in the current directory, but I can't find any way to pull them appart.

This will help in creating a timed script that runs in the background. Then I can apply a label in finder and expect an action automatically apply to that file without having to make special conditions or keep a curated file with a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ls`, you can show the extended metadata of files:

```
$ ls -l@
-rw-r--r--@ 1 andrew  staff  1292910 Aug  9 11:36 labelled_file.jpg
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_hlsi7t7nerhynemqvydgeb26de       50
```

However, the quickest way to get labelled and unlabelled files is with an attribute search using `mdfind`:

```
$ mdfind -onlyin . -literal 'kMDItemFSLabel > 0'  # labels have value 50
/cwd/labelled_file.jpg

$ mdfind -onlyin . -literal 'kMDItemFSLabel == 0'
/cwd/all.jpg
/cwd/other.jpg
/cwd/files.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo filename
```

but you will need some work to process the output. See [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/295151/mac-os-x-is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-color-ls-output-according-to-finder) for an example with a bash script and one with Python.

Comment: @dat5h if you find an answer useful please give an up vote and choose one of the answers as 'accepted'

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to mark-as-accepted, I had forgotten. Also, I'd give upvotes if I had the reputation required.